# Import data quickly using fabric or paramiko

Tags: python, sftp, fabric

I would like to import data from different servers, I used pysftp but it's working just when I do an ssh to the server and then I ran my script.

I would like to import data from different server in the same time by using fabric or pysftp if it's possible. I readied the documentation of fabric and didn't find a way to that. Waiting for your suggestions or same examples of that.

**Example**
 *

```
from fabric.api import*
filename = 'path/ip_address.txt'
while True:
    with open(filename) as f:
        data = f.readlines()
    env.hosts= data
    env.user= "usr"
    env.password="pwd"
    get("~/path/*.xml","localpath/pm_xml")
```

using this script I got an error message **No hosts found. Please specify (single) host string for connexion!**

and when I use paramiko this script:

```
import paramiko
import os
filename = "/home/test/Desktop/ip_address.txt"
with open(filename) as f:
    data = f.readlines()
while True:    
    for ipAddr in data:
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(ipAddr,username="usr",password="pwd")
        sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
        for element in sftp.listdir("server_path"):
            if element.endswith(".xml"):
                try:
                    sftp.get("server_path"+element,"/home/test/Documents/pm_xml/"+element)
                except:
                    print(Exception)
        sftp.close()
        ssh.close()
```

using paramiko I can only get one file per seconde but each server generate 100 files every minute.
my **ip_address.txt** contains ip address:

```
11.11.11.11
22.22.22.22
33.33.33.33
```

Any suggestions to get access in the same time to different server and import data quickly.

Comment: Yes, it's about speed. I edited my title.

Comment: First you have to investigate why it's that slow. Is it because the servers are slow? Or your connection is slow? Or you connection has a big latency?  Can you download the files from one server faster using any SFTP client?

Comment: why to you have to read parameters in the loop in first example and read it outside of loop in the second one?

Comment: @EPo in fact, when I use paramiko I should define the name of the element that I would to copy, so I should know its name in the server and then donwload it with the same name. fabric do that automatically. Not really sure!

Comment: @MartinPrikryl You are right it's due to the connection between the server and my machine! both are running in openstack and when I try to import data from a server in a different lab (for example in Finland) there is a big latency and when I use another server (in France) there is no more latency because the other machine where I run my script is also in France. So it's a question of connection I think.

Comment: From your test, I do not think it's clear, that the problem is latency and not bandwidth. Use some SFTP client to download two halves of files in two parallel transfers. And then download all files in one batch. If the first is twice faster, then the problem is the latency. If both approaches take about the same time, the problem is bandwidth.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I think I was not really clear, I will explain my example. Imagine that I have two machine and I could run my script in machine A or machine B; machine A is in lab in France and the other one in Finland. so when I am trying to import data in machineA from servers in Finland there is latency, but when I try to import data from servers in France there is no more latency. So when script and servers are in the same country (in others word the same lab) I can import data 1k files on only 1 minute. I will also check what you said ;)

Comment: I understood all that. I do not see any prove of the problem being latency in that. Was the problem bandwidth, the behavior would be all the same.